# How to optimise Core Data for many object insertions

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, insert

I am trying to insert about 400 objects in CoreData with in memory storage, but it is to long. For about 20-30 seconds. Is it normal? May be exists some special case for many insertions?

```
- (MyObject*) insertNew
{
    NSEntityDescription* entityDescr = [MyObject entityDescription];
    NSManagedObjectContext* ctx = [NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext];
    MyObject* obj = [[[MyObject alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescr
        insertIntoManagedObjectContext:ctx] autorelease];
    obj.name = @"name";
    obj.Id = @"an ID";
    return obj;
}
```

The objects are in hierarchical relationships to each other, like a tree.

Comment: Are you calling save on your managed object context 400 times (in a loop after each object for instance), or are you just calling save once?

Comment: Can you post your insertion code? That certainly seems slow.

Comment: @ BP. Once after all insertions

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any importing with Core Data, an essential read is [Core Data Programming Guide "Efficiently Importing Data".](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html)

It will potentially save you a massive amount of time, especially if the import is something that will be done repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

If this data will be imported the first time your App runs you may want to look at using a seed database, that way you can perform the slow import once during development, then it's just a matter of a small copy operation.

If your database is very large and space is at a premium you may want to look for another solution as this can use more disk space than necessary (seed database will be in the bundle and the documents directory).